# Django render multiple ModelForm in template and save

Tags: django, django-templates, modelform

I have a django **Entry** model which takes in several values related to an entity like height,weight etc. This value has to be entered every month. For each month, a new form along with the previous month's data has to be displayed on the template. My views look somewhat like this:

```
ntt=Entry.objects.get(pk=6)
lastmonth=EntryForm(instance=ntt)
thismonth=EntryForm()
return render(request, 'show.htm', {'thismonth':thismonth,'lastmonth':lastmonth})
```

I am not sure how to display the two values side by side, one line for each attribute like so:

```
<tr><td><input type=text>thismonth.weight</input></td><td>lastmonth.weight</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=text>thismonth.height</input></td><td>lastmonth.height</td></tr>
```

Using the common way of rendering a form like **{{thismonth.as_p}}{{lastmonth.as_p}}**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{thismonth.as_p}}</td>
<td>{{lastmonth.as_p}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I was able to render them on the same rows but with labels on both of them.

1. Is there a way to render the form where only the label will be displayed for **thismonth**, while **lastmonth** will only display the values and without manually specifying the field id and name?
2. Also, since I don't want to change the value of **lastmonth** is there a way to get only the **thismonth** values from **request.POST** in order to save/update it?

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, you can render each form field seperately like so basically:

```
[...]

<tr><td>{{ thismonth.as_p }}</td>
<td>{{ lastmonth.form_field }}</td></tr>

[...]
```

that way you can control which form's label should be rendered and which shouldn't.

2. yes, you can grab single values like so:

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = EntryForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            
            print form.cleaned_data['my_form_field_name']
            return [...]
```